# How to get awk to parse timestamp of form: 15:57:26.530

Tags: awk, timestamp

I have a file with a start line and an end line for a process and I want awk to print the time difference between start and end for all instances in the file.

Here is an example input file.

```
15:57:26.530 start of process [404] (00000002 5:52795
... lots of details I dont care abour
@15:57:26.8300 end of process [404]
15:57:33.330 start of process [324] (00000002 44:62792
... lots of details I dont care abour
@15:57:33.6300 end of process [324]
```

My awk script so far:

```
/start of process/ { 
    print $0; 
    st = $1;
}

/end of process/ { 
    print $0;
    now=mktime($1);
    start=mktime(st);
    print "time difference ", now-start, " seconds"; 
}
```

But it doesn't work because mktime doesn't like the format of the timestamp.  mktime requires the timestamp to be of the form: "YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]".

I could do string processing and convert the components of the timestamp string to numbers and then do the calculation but I was thinking there is probably an easier way.  Anyone?

### UPDATE

After feedback, I adjusted my script as follows.

```
function timeval(tstamp) {
    if(substr(tstamp, 1, 1) == "@")
      tstamp = substr($1, 2);
    else
     tstamp = $1;

  split (tstamp, arr, ":");
  return arr[1] * 3600 + arr[2] * 60 + arr[3];
}

/start of process/ { 
  print $0; 
  start = timeval($1);
}

/end of process/ { 
    print $0;
    print "time difference ", timeval($1)-start, " seconds\n"; 
}
```

### UPDATE2

For those late night sessions...

```
function timeval(tstamp) {
  sub(/^@/,"",tstamp);
  split (tstamp, arr, ":");
  return arr[1] * 3600 + arr[2] * 60 + arr[3];
}

/start of process/ { 
  print $0; 
  start = timeval($1);
}

/end of process/ { 
    print $0;
    end = timeval($1);
    print "time difference ", end + (start > end ? 86400 : 0) - start, " seconds\n"; 
}
```

Comment: You could replace the 4-line if/else in `timeval` with just a single `sub(/^@/,"",tstamp)`. Your time difference calculation will fail when your process starts before and ends after midnight, see my answer. You don't need all those null statements (trailing semi-colons).

Comment: Surely its safer to add the semi-colon on the end?

Comment: No, not at all, it just clutters up your code with a bunch of unnecessary but usually harmless symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're screwed if your start/end times can be greater than 24 hours because your timestamps don't have any date information so you can't tell if an end time is 5 mins after the start time or 1 day and 5 mins after the start time. Similarly if you need to take Daylight Savings Time into account (if you start 10 secs before DST advances the clock an hour, and end 10 secs after - should your process duration be reported as 20 secs or 1 hour and 20 secs?) you need dates and the timezone for your timestamps.

Given your current timestamp format mktime() can't help you and so isn't necessary.

Assuming there cannot be as big as 24 hours gap and you don't have DST concerns then you need something like this, using a modified version of your sample input to show cases where there are some number of seconds between the timestamps:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/start of process/ {
    print
    split($1,hms,/[:.]/)
    start = (hms[1] * 3600) + (hms[2] * 60) + hms[3]
}

/end of process/ {
    print
    split($1,hms,/[@:.]/)
    end = (hms[2] * 3600) + (hms[3] * 60) + hms[4]

    duration = end + (start > end ? 86400 : 0) - start

    print "time difference", duration , "seconds"
}

$ cat file
15:57:26.530 start of process [404] (00000002 5:52795
... lots of details I dont care abour
@15:57:46.8300 end of process [404]
23:59:33.330 start of process [324] (00000002 44:62792
... lots of details I dont care abour
@00:00:33.6300 end of process [324]

$ awk -f tst.awk file
15:57:26.530 start of process [404] (00000002 5:52795
@15:57:46.8300 end of process [404]
time difference 20 seconds
23:59:33.330 start of process [324] (00000002 44:62792
@00:00:33.6300 end of process [324]
time difference 60 seconds
```

The calculation of duration is to accommodate crossing midnight between start and end timestamps.

Your posted sample input always has zero seconds difference between the start and end times. If you want to go to milliseconds granularity just add `hms[4]` to the `start` calculation and `hms[5]` to the `end` and multiply all the other numbers by 1000.